# Magento: How to get the form_key value to an "external" php-file?

Tags: php, magento

I have had a custom HTML file where I have made a custom registration form for my Magento shop. This has worked flawless until an update where the hidden form_key input has been put into the original registration form.

Is there an easy way to get the form_key value sent tom my custom HTML-page (that I can rename to .php)?

I see that in the register.phtml the value is written using:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

Of course this doesn't work without some connection (API) with the Magento-store. But I am not familiar with that and not as good programmer.

**Is there a way to get the value (form_key) from the Magento store easily?**

- The custom registration form is placed on a php-file in the root of the Magento-store.
- Can I use a include() in my php file to get connected to Magento and thus get the above code to work?
- The Magento store admin says version 1.7.0.2, but it might have been updated by the company that keeps it patched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my issue has been to deactivate form_key, but on the registration form **only**. Or, more precise, I deactivated the form_key validation in the AccountController.php line 265.

Form_key is used elsewhere.

We have never had an issue with registration forms beeing submitted by robots etc, so for now that is a solution good enough.

Answer (score -1):

Why the heck you have custom form in separate file outside Magento?

Comment: Because that is the solution that worked best for us. The form_key have not been needed neighter. We dont use Magento as a normal shopping cart in all, and we needed a totally custom form that displays just like we need to. We don't have one, but many, custom registration forms. They add customers to different customer groups and also have custom success urls. + a lot of different layouts and content above the form.